# PHP Programmatically allow/deny domains

Tags: php, security, rest

I have got this REST API that has private and public api's. So in the code I allow and deny requests per API. I use this piece of code:

```
public function allowDomain($domain) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $domain);
}
```

Now after some research I am not too sure if this is a safe way of doing so (since of spoofing). Is this the right thing to do or is there something more? if so what?

Comment: Are you trying to deny access to client side JavaScript running on pages from other (untrusted) domains, or deny access to untrusted domains entirely?

Comment: @Quentin I need to deny it for JavaScript access and all other requests from untrusted domains.

Comment: @f.lorenzo — Then you need to use password based authentication, and not provide public JS access at all.

Comment: @Quentin But how would private JavaScript (from the same domain) be able to access it without putting passwords in the JavaSript file?

Comment: @f.lorenzo — It wouldn't. You can't  publish data, to the public, on your website without other people being able to read it.

Comment: @Quentin Then i guess its a waste of effort to protect against?

Answer (score 0):

To really secure your API (the private part) you should use Keys or Tokens. the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is only on client side, so Javscript doesn't request APIs where this isn't set for security reasons. You can still access this API in the Browser or somewhere else.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: But how would private JavaScript (from the same domain) be able to access it?

Comment: Just add a Key per GET: /local/api.php?key=254236234523452345 and check it in your API `if($_GET["key"]==254236234523452345)`